# Loss tensor not present in Tensorboard Graph

Tags: tensorflow

I want to see the `loss` tensor in the graph for my model. But it's not present in the graph image.

How to **visualize** `loss` on **tensorboard** ?

[image]

Comment: I see a "softmax_corss_entropy..." node in the graph. Is this your loss function?

Comment: Yeah my bad. That's there. :) 
Just a quick question, I am using weitghted `softmax_cross_entropy`, i.e., weights for each datapoint(not classes), which I am passing to this function. How to verify from tensorboard that it's indeed getting used ?